# Scala expression, I need understand its parts

Tags: scala, expression

Can you explain me :

1)
In PermSet , in line where val u initialized:
why it possible to write "file.*u*= _ "  ?
file._u I can understand, but not the rest...

2)

perms:(Perm => Unit, () => Perm)*  - what does it mean?

```
case class PermSet(file:FilePerms, perms:(Perm => Unit, () => Perm)* ) {

}



object PermSet {
    val u   =  (file:FilePerms) => new PermSet(file,(file._u_= _ , file._u _))
    val g   =  (file:FilePerms) => new PermSet(file,(file._g_= _ , file._g _))
    val o   =  (file:FilePerms) => new PermSet(file,(file._o_= _ , file._o _))
    ...
}



class FilePerms(
   var _u:Perm=none,
   var _g:Perm=none,
   var _o:Perm=none
) {
   ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The technical part

```
case class PermSet(file:FilePerms, perms:(Perm => Unit, () => Perm)* )
```

Is a case class that receives a concrete `FilePerms` instance as well as s variable numbers (0 or more) of `perms`.

Each perm is a `Tuple` of functions.

The first function of the pair `(Perm => Unit)` receives a `Perm` and does not return anything (`Unit`) - if you are a `c` or `java` guy, read `Unit` as `void`. So, the main use of this function should be mutating a `Perm` (a mutator aka setter).

The second function of the pair `(() => Perm)` is a function with no arguments that returns a `Perm` (looks like an accessor, aka getter).

Now for

```
val u = (file:FilePerms) => new PermSet(file, (file._u_= _ , file._u _))
```

`u` is a function that receives some concrete `FilePerms` and create a `PermSet` out of it.

- `(file._u_= _ , file._u _)` is a `Tuple`
- `file._u_= _` is a function that respects the defined contract for the first type of the `Tuple` (`Perm => Unit`)
- `file._u _` is also a function that respects the defined contract for the second type argument of the Tuple (`() => Perm`)

On `file._u_=`, `u_=` is an mutator method on `file` (an instance of `FilePerms`). The mutator receives a `Perm`, stores it in `file` and returns nothing (`Unit`). The  trailing `_` is a *magical* conversion operator that lets the setter **method** on `FilePerms` behave as a **function** (`Perm => Unit`)

In the same way, on `file._u _`, `_u` is a accessor method with no arguments (`()`) that returns a `Perm` (from `file`). Again `_` triggers a conversion where the accessor method gets expanded as a function (`() => Perm`).

If the difference between method and function is becoming foggy, specially with all of those `val`s around. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530007/664577) from Daniel Sobral.

### The conceptual part

This code is doing the following:

Declaring user (`u`), group (`g`) and other (`u`) instance permissions (`FilePerms`). Think of this class as the concrete permissions of a specific file or directory.

Declaring a case class `PermSet` that receives a instance of `FilePerms` and zero or more `perms`, which are nothing more than a Tuple of functions that can mutate and access a permission. The purpose of this class is to wrap instance permissions in a way to expose only permissions that you want someone to be able to access and or mutate. The hidden conceptual key word here is `grant`. The file have permissions `FilePerms`, of those, you can filter the ones that should be exposed using a `PermSet`.

Finally, `PermSet` companion object is declaring some permissions (`u`, `g`, `o`) (think of them as Java `static` methods), each one will receive a instance of `FilePerms` and return a `PermSet` capable of mutating and accessing that particular permission. So think of them as *static methods* capable of extracting default `PermSet`s out of `FileSet`. E.g. `u(myFile)` will return a `PermSet` able to access and manipulate `myFile` user permissions.

Answer (score 2):

2) `perms:(Perm => Unit, () => Perm)*`:

- a star `*` symbol means that function takes a variable number of arguments of this type.
- The (X, Y) form is a pair or `Tuple2[+T1, +T2]`.
- `Perm => Unit` means that you need to pass a function that takes a `Perm` argument and returns `Unit` - basically returns nothing, so it most likely doing side effecting. Similarly `() => Perm` means that it expects a function with no args that returns a `Perm`.

1) Underscore `_` is a placeholder - a variable will be placed in there when the function is called. So if you have this syntax `file._u_= _` then it means that some value will placed on the right side of `=` in place of `_` when this code is called and then assigned to `file._u`. Assignment does not return anything, i.e `Unit`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler automatically generates a getter and setter for each class property.

```
class FilePerms {
    var _u:Perm=none
}
```

in essence becomes

```
class FilePerms {
    private var __u:Perm=none

    // Getter
    def _u = __u

    // Setter
    def _u_=(v:Perm) {
        __u = v
    }
}
```

So `file._u_=` is the setter for the `_u` property.

When you want to access a method as an object, you add an underscore after it.

If you want to pass the setter to another method or constructor, you would say

```
file._u_= _
```